# The button in express not working for me and have no error codes

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning express node.js and trying to run simple calculator code but anytime i press on the button i don't get any response back and also i don't get any errors in my code so i am kind of lost of what i am doin wrong. here is the sample of it so hoping someone can pinpoint me where i am goin wrong will include html code and calculator.js. Thank you in advance.

```
index.html
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder = "first number" value="">
      <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="second number" value="">
      <button type="button" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
  </body>

calculator.js

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);

  var result = num1 + num2;

  //this line to show result in hyper
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("The result is: " + result);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: you're button has to include `type=submit` instead of `type=button`. you need to specify what you want the button to do in the type. give that a try and lmk if it wroks

Comment: no problem. I'll add it as an answer for future reference. if you need any more help lmk!

Comment: No problem, if i do i will ask you thank you again

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in your button type. To submit a form using a button in html, you need to specify the type not as `button`, but as `type`.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder = "first number" value="">
      <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="second number" value="">
      <button type="submit" name="submit>Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button type should be submit
And. Name:button

Also you have to convert the values into  numbers in order to avoid string concatenate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).